# Hagan et. al original argument for SABR

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, sabr, sabr-model

In the original SABR paper (Hagan et al 2002 ), the introduction of the famous model is motivated by the observation that local volatility models spot dynamics work the wrong way. As the spot increases the implied vol decreases- and conversely- which is at odd with markets. Thus the necessity of an alternative parametrization. In the introduction they write

*"The dynamic behaviour of smiles and skews predicted by local vol model is exactly opposite the behavior observed in the marketplace: when the price of the underlying asset decreases local vol models predict that the smiles shifts to higher prices; when the price increases, these models predict that the smile shift to lower prices. In reality, asset prices and market smiles move in the same direction"*

In contrast, according to the authors (pag 15) :

*..The SABR model also predicts that whenever the forward price $f$ changes, the the (sic) implied volatility curve shifts in the same direction and by the same amount as the price $f$.*

I do not understand where in the paper this claim is supported. Actually, what I see from the implied vol expansion is that the backbone of the ATM  volatility $\sigma(f,f)$, which is $\alpha/f^{1-\beta}$, for fixed $\alpha$ ,decreases as $f$ increases. Analogoulsy all the other volatilities, in direct contrast with the claim. What is more, is that if $\alpha$ can move, and as logical we are in the situation $\rho <0$ because of the vol skew/leverage, then as $f$ increases $\alpha$ will have a tendency to decrease, depressing further the ATM ivol.

Am I getting this wrong? Can somebody explain?

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Patrick_Hagan3/publication/235622441_Managing_Smile_Risk/links/59e4d89f458515250246e626/Managing-Smile-Risk.pdf

Comment: The whole idea that an increased spot yields increased volatilies is what is puzzling me. This is not what I know of spot/vol realations. Or maybe this is not what the authors mean; the use of  vague expressions such as "move" or "shift" instead of decrease/increase contributes to create ambiguity, so I am not sure what I am inferring is what the authors mean.

Comment: it's discussed starting in pp 87 from "To illustrate the problem, consider the special case in which the local vol is a function of ˆF only:"...